# How to model the transtition part of dispersive frequency shift in dispersive readout?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation

The phenomenon of interest is the resonance frequency shift and the larger noise in the measurements inside the intermediate-powered region as shown below (from Fig. 3.3 of [*Characterisation of Transmon qubit chips*, L. M. Janssen](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid:73cbbe3c-8021-4e85-9512-948baf828ff4/datastream/OBJ/download).

[image]

If I understand correctly, in the low-powered regime we can employ dispersive approximation to simplify the JC model into (cf. [*A Quantum Engineer’s Guide to Superconducting Qubits*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560) Eq. 144 -- Eq. 147)

$$
H_\mathrm{disp}=\omega_r\left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_q+\frac{g^2}{\Delta}+\frac{2g^2}{\Delta}a^\dagger a\right)\sigma_z
$$

But when the photon number $n>n_c=\Delta^2/(4g^2)$, the approximation breaks down and we go into the region of interest. Literature seems to suggest that we need to go beyond RWA (e.g., Eq. 2 of [*Measurement-induced state transitions in a superconducting qubit: Beyond the rotating wave approximation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05721)) but I am not entirely sure.

Also, can we combine such a model with the notch-typed resonator model, i.e., Eq. 1 in [*Efficient and robust analysis of complex scattering data under noise in microwave resonators*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3365)?

(There seems to be a relevant question on QC@SE but it gets no answer: [Many-photon limit of dispersive shift Hamiltionian](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12597/11579) .)